# Custom config elements collection in Web.config - Using a key to choose

Tags: c#, web-config, configurationsection

### Intro

I'm developing a WebApp built on C# ASP.NET.

I've been researching creating a "Custom Configuration" section with child elements in the `Web.config` file, and I've hit a bit of a snag when it comes to consuming the keys/values in the data.

I seem to be going round in circles and I don't know how to tackle the issue I'm having.

---

### Situation

I have a few different Connection Strings defined in the `Web.Config` file, in the `<connectionStrings>` section. They are for dev, test, and live databases.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionOne" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
    <add name="connectionTwo" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
    <add name="connectionThree" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

The WebApp is currently hard-coded to use one of these connection strings - if I need to change which one to use, I need to re-compile.

---

### Desired Functionality

I'd like to define a section in the `Web.config`, let's say `DbSettings`.

In that, I'd then like to be able to define some child elements for, let's say `DbSetting`s, in which I could define `dbConnectionName`, `foo`, `bar` etc. as attributes.

For example:

```
<dbSettings>
    <dbSetting key="DbSetting1"
                     dbConnectionName="connectionOne"
                     foo="fooOne"
                     bar="barOne" />
   ... and so on
</dbSettings>
```

Then, perhaps in the `<appSettings>` section, define which of these `DbSetting`s elements I want to use to get the settings from:

```
<appSettings>
    <add name="dbSettingsKey" value="DbSetting1" />
</appSettings>
```

---

### Desired Web.config section

Here is a fuller example of what I'd imagine my `Web.config` file to look like:

**Connection Strings**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionOne" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
    <add name="connectionTwo" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
    <add name="connectionThree" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

**App Settings**

```
<add key="dbSettingsKey" value="DbSetting1" /> // or 2, or 3 etc.
```

**DbSettings** *(custom section)*

```
<dbSettings>
    <dbSetting key="DbSetting1"
                     dbConnectionName="connectionOne"
                     foo="fooOne"
                     bar="barOne" />
    <dbSetting key="DbSetting2"
                     dbConnectionName="connectionTwo"
                     foo="fooTwo"
                     bar="barTwo" />
    <dbSetting key="DbSetting3"
                     dbConnectionName="connectionThree"
                     foo="fooThree"
                     bar="barThree" />
</dbSettings>
```

---

### My question...

How the devil am I going to get this desired functionality in the C# code?

I've read loads on "creating your own custom section", and similarly "creating a custom config collection". But, I just can't seem to glue it all together to apply for my situation.

I'd like to be able to have a class (like the one I'm using at the moment with the hard-coded strings), which I can reference necessary properties *(as I am doing, at the moment)* - and then the code can dynamically load the correct settings at run-time from the sections I've described above.

As always, thank you in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: You're overcomplicating.. You need one connection string with one name, and different values in your different environments.

Comment: Thanks @JasonP - I was thinking the same thing with the connection string, to be honest *sanity check*. However, connection string(s) aside; let's say I wanted to added a custom section with a collection in (like in OP), and then choose which key to refer to from an `<appSettings>` key. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: Yes, creating a custom config section is a common problem, and there should be plenty of tutorials out there. Once you've done that, you can get the connection string using the variable containing the value: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringToUse]`

Comment: Thanks again, @JasonP - I'll come back to the custom config sections when I've cleared my head a little. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments. The way this is usually done is you deploy a different web.config to each environment. When your deployment group (or you) deploys, you deploy everything *EXCEPT* the web.config unless you have changes to push.

In answer to your other question, adding a custom section is not trivial. It's quite a bit of work. Custom section handler which requires a whole bunch of configuration element classes and a bunch of configuration element collection classes... and then, if you want it to "work" correctly, you also need to create a schema and register that with the IDE, etc.

For your particular case, I'd just do it the "normal" way :).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Sledgehammer! I'll come back to the custom sections with a clearer head and have a re-think of how I can address the deployment as well :)